# How Active Device Registered count for Notification Hub can be decreased

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

Could somebody shed a light in following situation:
Yesterday I reviewed Notification Hub blade in Azure portal for our Development notification hub and there were **872** Active Registered Devices. Today I see only **656** Active Registered Devices:
[image]

At the same time this notification hub doesn't have Registration Time to Live, on Properties tab I see *Registration Time to Live = 10,675,199 days*. So I suppose that devices are still registered but they maybe are **inactive** now.

So my questions are:

- How Azure determine that device is active?
- Does it mean that the apps cannot sent notifications to inactive devices?

Answer (score 0):

When a Push Notification Service (PNS) notifies Azure Notification Hubs that the device token is invalid, Notification Hubs flags the registration for deletion. A housekeeping task runs periodically and deletes those registrations automatically.

Yes, apps cannot send notifications to inactive devices. For example, when a user uninstalls an app, the existing device token won't work anymore (There's no associated app on the device to respond). When the same user reinstalls the app, a new device token is generated, making the old one invalid as well.